# Post to Twitter wall

Tags: android, twitter

I am using this simple way to post text to my wall:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse("http://twitter.com/?status=" + Uri.encode("Athens: 10% OFF + FREE Dessert, Coffee: http://www.itsrelevant.com/contnet/1814/Athens_10pct_OFF_FREE_Dessert_Coffee?ref=y9s1ca")));
startActivity(i);
```

Is there any way to post a complete deal info like picture, web link and a message?

Comment: [This](http://www.androidsnippets.com/post-a-tweet-on-twitter) snippet shows a bit more fleshed out example of how you can post a more complex message to twitter from an android application. If you want to attach an image to your message, perhaps it would be easier to use a service like [yfrog.com](http://yfrog.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

Actually this way of posting data to a web service is wrong.

You better open an Http connection to the service and then try to Http Post the data that you want to the server.But in this case you need to know if the service is supporting and handling the kind of post request that you are sending.

You better check Twitter Api for your questions about sending a picture or web link etc and configure your Http Post according to that.

https://dev.twitter.com/

Comment: +1 agree with this, check the API and make a request structure accordingly.